# Ошибки при компиляции приложения в Qt Creator Ubuntu

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu, qtcreator

[image: Screenshot]

Пример вывода ниже:

```
20:09:46: Выполняются этапы для проекта QFile...
20:09:46: Запускается: «/usr/bin/make» clean
rm -f moc_mainwindow.cpp moc_dialog.cpp
rm -f ui_mainwindow.h ui_dialog.h
rm -f main.o mainwindow.o dialog.o moc_mainwindow.o moc_dialog.o
rm -f *~ core *.core
20:09:46: Процесс «/usr/bin/make» завершился успешно.
20:09:46: Настройки не изменились, этап qmake пропускается.
20:09:46: Запускается: «/usr/bin/make» 
/opt/Qt5.7.0/5.7/gcc_64/bin/uic ../QFile/mainwindow.ui -o ui_mainwindow.h
/opt/Qt5.7.0/5.7/gcc_64/bin/uic ../QFile/dialog.ui -o ui_dialog.h
g++ -c -pipe -g -std=gnu++11 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DQT_QML_DEBUG    -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I../QFile -I. -I/opt/Qt5.7.0/5.7/gcc_64/include -I/opt/Qt5.7.0/5.7/gcc_64/include/QtWidgets -I/opt/Qt5.7.0/5.7/gcc_64/include/QtGui -I/opt/Qt5.7.0/5.7/gcc_64/include/QtCore -I. -I. -I/opt/Qt5.7.0/5.7/gcc_64/mkspecs/linux-g++ -o main.o ../QFile/main.cpp
g++ -c -pipe -g -std=gnu++11 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I../QFile -I. -I/opt/Qt5.7.0/5.7/gcc_64/include -I/opt/Qt5.7.0/5.7/gcc_64/include/QtWidgets -I/opt/Qt5.7.0/5.7/gcc_64/include/QtGui -I/opt/Qt5.7.0/5.7/gcc_64/include/QtCore -I. -I. -I/opt/Qt5.7.0/5.7/gcc_64/mkspecs/linux-g++ -o mainwindow.o ../QFile/mainwindow.cpp
In file included from ../QFile/mainwindow.cpp:4:0:
./QFile:1:1: error: stray '\177' in program
ELF         >    �9@     @       0I         @ 8   @ ( %       @       @ @     @ @     �      �                   8      8@     8@                                          @       @     ��      ��                    ��      ��`     ��`                                 Ѝ      Ѝ`     Ѝ`                                T      T@     T@     D       D              P�td   �o      �o@     �o@     $      $             Q�td                                                  R�td   ��      ��`     ��`                        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2          GNU                        GNU ���y�Þ�_1�6������}I   �         ��  @ �   �   �   ���|CE���qX������                        �                     q                      2                     �                     ?                     "                     �                                          �                     \                     �                     �                     \                                          W
 ^
./QFile:1:1: error: stray '\2' in program
./QFile:1:1: error: stray '\1' in program
./QFile:1:1: error: stray '\1' in program
./QFile:1:1: error: stray '\3' in program
./QFile:1:9: warning: null character(s) ignored
 ELF         >    �9@     @       0I         @ 8   @ ( %       @       @ @     @ @     �      �                   8      8@     8@                                          @       @     ��      ��                    ��      ��`     ��`                                 Ѝ      Ѝ`     Ѝ`                                T      T@     T@     D       D              P�td   �o      �o@     �o@     $      $             Q�td                                                  R�td   ��      ��`     ��`                        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2          GNU                        GNU ���y�Þ�_1�6������}I   �         ��  @ �   �   �   ���|CE���qX������                        �                     q                      2                     �                     ?                     "                     �                                          �                     \                     �                     �                     \                                          W
^
./QFile:1:1: error: stray '\2' in program
 ELF         >    �9@     @       0I         @ 8   @ ( %       @       @ @     @ @     �      �                   8      8@     8@                                          @       @     ��      ��                    ��      ��`     ��`                                 Ѝ      Ѝ`     Ѝ`                                T      T@     T@     D       D              P�td   �o      �o@     �o@     $      $             Q�td                                                  R�td   ��      ��`     ��`                        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2          GNU                        GNU ���y�Þ�_1�6������}I   �         ��  @ �   �   �   ���|CE���qX������                        �                     q                      2                     �                     ?                     "                     �                                          �                     \                     �                     �                     \                                          W
^
./QFile:1:18: warning: null character(s) ignored
ELF         >    �9@     @       0I         @ 8   @ ( %       @       @ @     @ @     �      �                   8      8@     8@                                          @       @     ��      ��                    ��      ��`     ��`                                 Ѝ      Ѝ`     Ѝ`                                T      T@     T@     D       D              P�td   �o      �o@     �o@     $      $             Q�td                                                  R�td   ��      ��`     ��`                        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2          GNU                        GNU ���y�Þ�_1�6������}I   �         ��  @ �   �   �   ���|CE���qX������                        �                     q                      2                     �                     ?                     "                     �                                          �                     \                     �                     �                     \                                          W
^
./QFile:1:20: warning: null character(s) ignored
 ELF         >    �9@     @       0I         @ 8   @ ( %       @       @ @     @ @     �      �                   8      8@     8@                                          @       @     ��      ��                    ��      ��`     ��`                                 Ѝ      Ѝ`     Ѝ`                                T      T@     T@     D       D              P�td   �o      �o@     �o@     $      $             Q�td                                                  R�td   ��      ��`     ��`                        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2          GNU                        GNU ���y�Þ�_1�6������}I   �         ��  @ �   �   �   ���|CE���qX������                        �                     q                      2                     �                     ?                     "                     �                                          �                     \                     �                     �                     \                                          W
^
./QFile:1:1: error: stray '\1' in program
 ELF         >    �9@     @       0I         @ 8   @ ( %       @       @ @     @ @     �      �                   8      8@     8@                                          @       @     ��      ��                    ��      ��`     ��`                                 Ѝ      Ѝ`     Ѝ`                                T      T@     T@     D       D              P�td   �o      �o@     �o@     $      $             Q�td                                                  R�td   ��      ��`     ��`                        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2          GNU                        GNU ���y�Þ�_1�6������}I   �         ��  @ �   �   �   ���|CE���qX������                        �                     q                      2                     �                     ?                     "                     �                                          �                     \                     �                     �                     \                                          W
 ^
```

Также код самого файла, на который ссылается компилятор:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QFile>
#include <QDir>
#include <QTextStream>
#include "dialog.h"
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    setCentralWidget(ui->textEdit);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_actionRead_triggered()
{
    Dialog *wnd=new Dialog(this);
    wnd->show();

    connect(wnd, SIGNAL(FilePath(QString)), this,  SLOT(ReadToFile(QString)));
}

void MainWindow::ReadToFile(const QString &filePath)
{
    QFile mFile(filePath);

    if(mFile.open(QFile::ReadOnly | QFile::Text))
    {
        QMessageBox::information(this, "Error", "Path isn't correct");
        return;
    }

    QTextStream stream(&mFile);

    QString buffer=stream.readAll();

ui->textEdit->setText(buffer);

}
```

До этого собирал на семерке и ничего подобного не встречал. Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Код и сообщения об ошибках должны быть текстом!

Comment: Там вываливается более 300к однотипных ошибок. Я понимаю, что нужен текст, но собирал готовый код, который на семерке работают, никаких ошибок там нет, вот и подумал, что у меня неверная конфигурация компилятора или еще что-то, чего я не знаю, а в этом случае сомневаюсь, что код вам помог бы.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Кратко

Проблема возникает из-за совпадения имени проекта (`QFile`) с именем одного из заголовочных файлов, идущих в комплекте с Qt. Для устранения конфликта переименуйте проект, либо (на правах костыля) выполните очистку сборочного окружения (<kbd>Сборка → Очистить</kbd>).

### Подробно

Первое, что бросается в глаза — это обилие ошибок компиляции вида *«stray '...' in program»*. Оно означает, что в тексте программы была встречена последовательность недопустимых символов *(к допустимым относятся латинские буквы, цифры и знаки препинания, иными словами, вся ISO 8859-5)*. Как правило, это происходит из-за использования юникодовых символов.

Однако следующая же строка ошибки показывает, что это не тот случай:

> ```
> ELF         >    �9@     @       0I         @ 8   @ ( %       @       @ @     @ @     �      �                   8      8@     8@                                          @       @     ��      ��                    ��      ��`     ��`                                 Ѝ      Ѝ`     Ѝ`                                T      T@     T@     D       D              P�td   �o      �o@     �o@     $      $             Q�td                                                  R�td   ��      ��`     ��`                        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2          GNU                        GNU ���y�Þ�_1�6������}I   �         ��  @ �   �   �   ���|CE���qX������                        �                     q                      2                     �                     ?                     "                     �                                          �                     \                     �                     �                     \                                          W
> ```

Похоже, что `QFile` — это вообще не файл исходных кодов. Судя по обилию странных и бессвязных символов, это двоичный файл, а начальное `ELF` показывает, что это Linux-овский исполняемый или объектный файл.

Как он вообще сюда затесался? Неужели при обработке `CMakeList.txt` произошёл сбой, и CMake повторно натравил на объектный файл компилятор вместо компоновщика? Ниже ничего интересного нет, так что идём вверх:

> ```
> In file included from ../QFile/mainwindow.cpp:4:0:
> ```

Так, CMake здесь не при чём, с заголовочными (раз `include`-им) файлами он не работает. Смотрим, как именно производится включение в четвёртой строке файла `mainwindow.cpp`:

> ```
> #include <QFile>
> ```

Обращаем внимание, что имя подключаемого файла подозрительно совпадает с именем проекта. Это должно насторожить, потому что Qt именует выходной исполняемый файл (помним про начальное `ELF`) по имени проекта, плюс в Linux-е исполняемые файлы традиционно не имеют расширений.

Для подтверждения гипотезы о конфликте имён смотрим, где компилятор выполняет поиск заголовочных файлов, благо в журнале сборки любезно предоставлены все ключи компиляции:

> ```
> g++ -c -pipe -g -std=gnu++11 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I../QFile -I. -I/opt/Qt5.7.0/5.7/gcc_64/include -I/opt/Qt5.7.0/5.7/gcc_64/include/QtWidgets -I/opt/Qt5.7.0/5.7/gcc_64/include/QtGui -I/opt/Qt5.7.0/5.7/gcc_64/include/QtCore -I. -I. -I/opt/Qt5.7.0/5.7/gcc_64/mkspecs/linux-g++ -o mainwindow.o ../QFile/mainwindow.cpp
> ```

Нас интересуют все вхождения ключа `-I`, указывающего места поиска заголовочных файлов. При этом поиск производится в том порядке, в котором эти пути были перечислены:

1. ../QFile
2. .
3. /opt/Qt5.7.0/5.7/gcc_64/include
4. /opt/Qt5.7.0/5.7/gcc_64/include/QtWidgets
5. /opt/Qt5.7.0/5.7/gcc_64/include/QtGui
6. /opt/Qt5.7.0/5.7/gcc_64/include/QtCore
7. .
8. .
9. /opt/Qt5.7.0/5.7/gcc_64/mkspecs/linux-g++

Итак, что делает компилятор при встрече строки `#include <QFile>`:

1. Берёт первый путь в списке (`../QFile`).
2. Пытается открыть файл `../QFile/QFile`.
3. Так как CMake устанавливает текущей корневую директорию для сборки (чьё имя устанавливается в имя проекта), то `../QFile` эквивалентно `.`, то есть текущей корневой директории сборки. По счастливой случайности, именно сюда CMake кладёт итоговый исполняемый файл.
4. Если указанный файл существует, то компилятор останавливает поиск и берёт именно его.
5. Однако этот файл является «хвостом» от предыдущей сборки. Соответственно, если сборка производится в чистом окружении, то компилятор не находит файла `../QFile/QFile`, и идёт по списку дальше, пока не дойдёт до `/opt/Qt5.7.0/5.7/gcc_64/include/QtCore`, где и лежит правильный заголовочный файл.